# Why is the first value 2814, but not after I remove an block of code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

So I have an variable value4 that I assign to a value of 14, but it says that it's value is actually 2814...
But whenever I remove a block of code (I marked it with comments 
"starts here" and "ends here"), it all acts normal again. I would like to know, what part causes it & why is it like that - and of course, how I fix?

```
Here's the function:
void incByOne(int &ref) {
    ++ref;
}
```

Here's the code:

```
// *starts here*
int *ptr = new int; // dynamically allocate an integer
*ptr = 28; // put a value in that memory location

if (!ptr) {
    std::cout << "Could not allocate memory.";
    exit(1);
}

std::cout << *ptr;
delete ptr;
// *ends here*

ptr = 0;

int value4 = 14;
int &ref = value4;
ref = value4;
std::cout << value4 << std::endl;
ref = 99;
std::cout << value4 << std::endl;
incByOne(value4);
std::cout << value4 << std::endl;
```

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question with an [mcve] or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: The code between the comments prints the value 28..

Comment: Using `new int` seems pretty silly, WHY??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It isn't undefined, he just missed a newline

Comment: @cocarin Just spotted that, removed the UB part from my comment. VTC that now.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Well, ... is it a typo, or a misunderstanding about how output works?

Comment: @Angew Well, doesn't matter much IMHO. At earlier times being around here, I would have said (and actually did so): _"There are no silly questions."_ I well know better today ;-) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you print the value `ptr` it prints `28`, but you don't insert a newline before printing `value4` for the first time.

This means that you're printing

```
2814
```

`28` - Value of `*ptr`

`14` - Value of `value4`

Insert a `std::endl` after printing `std::cout << *ptr;` and it should format correctly.

Answer (score 4):

You get `28` from the line

```
std::cout << *ptr;
```

Then, you get `14` from the first line

```
std::cout << value4 << std::endl;
```

Since there is no space or newline printed after the line that outputs `28`, you get `2814` as the output.